# JQuery: Adding onClick function to anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery

My anchor element is dynamically created when my document is `ready`:

```
var editLink = $('<a>', {html: 'Quick Edit', href: '#'});
$(editLink).click(editGameFunction(game.id, tr));
```

`editGameFunction` then contains code to invoke a JSON URL and perform some handling of this JSON

The problem is that `editGameFunction` is being invoked on launching of my document.

How do I set this such that it is not eagerly invoked?

Also, is there a better way to achieve what I'm doing without having to set the `href` attribute to be a dummy value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
$(editLink).click(function(){
    editGameFunction(game.id, tr);
});
```

instead of

```
$(editLink).click(editGameFunction(game.id, tr));
```

other option is to use `bind`